# Push only part of the history with magit

Tags: magit

I’m creating a big feature in one of our projects, that is close to around 20 commits in my local repository. Most of them are still subject to change with rebasing, but I’d like to push the first few stable ones for review already.

In the command line, I’d do

```
git push origin affec75:master
```

(given that `affec75` is a commit somewhere in my local history.)

I tried <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> (explicit refspecs), specifying `origin` as the remote and `affec75` as the refspec, but it failed. As the generated command is `git push origin affec75`, I tried setting `affec75:master` as the refspec; it succeeds, but it’s a real pain to type. Is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Move to the commit.
2. <kbd>P o</kbd> to push "another branch" (despite the description in the popup, this can also push arbitrary commits).
3. <kbd>RET</kbd> confirm the default source, which should be the abbreviated commit hash. If a branch points at the commit, then the commit is the second choice.
4. <kbd>RET</kbd> confirm the default target, which should be the current branch. (But only if the commit is reachable from `HEAD`.)

Comment: Thank you, [I did](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2820).

Comment: Doesn't `P o` work for this?

Comment: You're right. But it should be made a bit smarter by offering  the appropriate branch as default choice.

Comment: and… the feature is implemented ! It's based on `P o`.

Comment: If you incorporate it in the answer, I’ll accept it! Oh, and Kudos for the quick implementation!

Comment: Getting to it...